# Php - Return the day of the week only once in a drop down menu using multi-purpose array from DB query

Tags: php, arrays, loops, foreach

PHP 7 
I am trying to list, in a drop down menu button that is dynamically driven, the days of the week if they are present in a query. However I only want one result to print per day even though there will be more.

**For example**: if there are 12 customers assigned on a Monday, I only want the one 'Monday' result to print in my drop down menu. [This is an example of](http://www.bootply.com/0Pa60vxbnD) how the drop down button should perform in regards to listing days if present in the query. #note that the `Customer` table has 2 entries for Wed as indicated in the `Customers` button drop down, but I only want Wed listed once in the drop down for `Routes`.

*Basically the query gets * from a table where a user_id = 'session_id', this orders by a day column that is in numerical form in the DB; 1-7 for Mon-Sun.

```
$sql = "
SELECT * 
FROM  `customers` 
WHERE  `users_id` =  '1'
ORDER BY  `cust_route_day` ASC 
LIMIT 0 , 30";
$cust = new User;
$results = $cust->db->query($sql);
```

`User` comes from a user class that connects to DB and performs various queries.
Definitions and declarations.

```
$custName = array();
$custRouteDay = array();
$custID = array();
while ($row = $results->fetch_assoc())
{
    $custName[] = $row['cust_first_name'].' '.$row['cust_last_name'];
    $custRouteDay[] = $row['cust_route_day'];
    $custID[] = $row['cust_id'];
}
define("CUSTID", $custID);
define("USER_TASKS", [
    'Task Info' => 'Task Info',
    'Task Time' => 'Task Time',
    'Customer Route Info' => 'Customer Route Info',
    'Set Alert' => 'Set Alert'
]);
define("CUSTOMERS", $custName);
define("USER_TASKS", $userTasks);
// Assign the abbr value of day ex: 'Wed' to numerical value from DB ex: '2'
foreach(CUST_ROUTE_DAY as $key => $value){
    $newKey .= ROUTEDAY[$value]." ";
    $custRouteKeyArray = explode(" ",$newKey);
}

define("NAVICONS", [
    "glyphicon glyphicon-user",
    "glyphicon glyphicon-road",
    "glyphicon glyphicon-tasks",
    "fa fa-sitemap",
    "fa fa-globe"
]);
define( "STYLE", [
    "fixed-bottom" => "navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-bottom",
    "fixed-top" => "navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top",
    "default" => "navbar navbar-default"
]);
define("NAVBTNS", [
    "Customers"=>CUSTOMERS,
    "Route Info"=>$custRouteKeyArray,
    "Tasks"=>USER_TASKS,
    "Networking",
    "Maps"
]);
```

The defined array `NAVBTNS`:

```
Array ( [0] => John Banner [1] => Dale Landry [2] => Bill Childers [3] => Darren Little [4] => Gary Garland ) Array ( [0] => Mon [1] => Wed [2] => Wed [3] => Thur [4] => Fri [5] => ) Array ( [Task Info] => Task Info [Task Time] => Task Time [Customer Route Info] => Customer Route Info [Set Alert] => Set Alert ) NetworkingMaps
```

The function that creates the Navigation menu btns and drop down btn. Basically if the array consists of sub arrays, create a drop down button and assign the key and values appropriately.

```
function construct_navbar_buttons(){
//because key values in the parent array are mixed numerical and char values
//define and increment $i each time through the loop for NAVICONS class values and page number key
$i = 0;
//Start the post variable that will hold the result string $btns <ul>
$btns = '<ul class="nav navbar-nav">';
foreach(NAVBTNS as $k => $v){//$k holds index or e.g. Customers  
    if(is_array($v)){//go over subarray else print button see //we have a string value
        $filtered = array_filter($v);//array_filter to remove null values
        if(empty($filtered)) {
            $btns .= '<li><a href="?p='.$v.'"><i class="'.NAVICONS[$i].'"></i>&nbsp;&nbsp;'.$v.'</a></li>';
        }else{//start drop down here
            $btns .= '<li class="dropdown">
                        <a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="">
                            <i class="'.NAVICONS[$i].'"></i>&nbsp;&nbsp;'.$k.'&nbsp;&nbsp;<span class="caret">&nbsp;</span>
                        </a>
                        <ul class="dropdown-menu dropdown-user">';
            foreach($v as $key => $value){//loop through results of child array
                if(in_array($v[$key], $v)){ //locate instance where key exists and print list-item a tag button in drop-down
                    ################################################################
                    ## need logic to go over first instance of a value within the ##
                    ## parent array to print only that first value in the results ##
                    ################################################################

                    $btns .= '<li><a href="?p='.$k.'&n='.$v[$key].'">'.$v[$key].'</a></li>';
                }
            }

            $btns .= "</ul>\n</li>";//close the parent UL and LI tags

        }
    }else{//we have a string value
        //do stuff  example data: Tasks  - key here seems aways a index number 
        $btns .= '<li><a href="?p='.$v.'"><i class="'.NAVICONS[$i].'"></i>&nbsp;&nbsp;'.$v.'</a></li>';
    }
    $i++;print_r($v);       
  }
  $btns .= '</ul>';
  return $btns;
}
```

Tried using `array_search`, but this is not giving me the results I hoped for

```
$d = array_search($value, $v);
if($d = ROUTEDAY[$i]){
    echo $value;
}

$day = array("Mon","Tue","Wed","Thur","Fri","Sat","Sun");
    if($d = $day[$i]){
        echo $day[$i];
    }
```

`ROUTEDAY` is a defined variable that holds the days of the week with keys values, gives me the following results on a simple echo.
1 - `MonWedWedThurFriTask InfoTask TimeCustomer Route InfoSet Alert`
2 - `MonTueWed`
**I thought array_search only gave you the first occurrence of a value in an array.**

I have tried creating separate foreach loops for each instance of an array, but that complicates things and I wish to get this done using the two foreach loops only. I am so close to getting this. If anyone could help I would be very grateful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK for the sake of others that may be searching for a similar answer, I figured out how to make this work.

I changed the redefined array to assign abbr. to numerical value for week day, here:

```
    foreach(CUST_ROUTE_DAY as $key => $value){
        $newKey .= ROUTEDAY[$value]." ";
        $custRouteKeyArray = explode(" ",$newKey);
    }
```

To the following:

```
$day = array("Mon"=>0,"Tue"=>1,"Wed"=>2,"Thur"=>3,"Fri"=>4,"Sat"=>5,"Sun"=>6);
 $d = array();
 foreach($day as $days=>$key){
    if(in_array($key, $custRouteDay)){
        $d[] = ROUTEDAY[$key];

    }
 }
```

This gives me:`Array ( [0] => Mon [1] => Wed [2] => Thur [3] => Fri )`

I use this value in my NAVBTNS array:

```
define("NAVBTNS", [
    "Customers"=>CUSTOMERS,
    "Route Info"=>$d,
    "Tasks"=>USER_TASKS,
    "Networking",
    "Maps"
]);
```

*Problem solved!